# Propagating value changes with Observables

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I use Observables to carry values from parent to child components.

Here is my top level app component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Observer } from 'rxjs/Observer';
import { ViewModel } from './ViewModel.data';
import { ViewComponent } from './ViewComponent.component';

@Component({
    selector: ...,
    directives: [
        ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,
        ViewComponent
    ],
    precompile: [],
    styles: [],
    template: `
            <div>
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
              <li *ngFor="let v of views"><a (click)="setView(v)">{{ v.name }}</a></li>
            </ul>
              <viewcomponent
                *ngFor="let v of views"
                [viewName]="v.name"
                [activeViewObservable]="activeViewObservable"></viewcomponent>
            </div>
    `
})
export class AppComponent{
    views:ViewModel[];
    activeViewObservable:Observable<ViewModel>;
    viewObserver:Observer<ViewModel>;
    activeView:ViewModel;

    constructor() {
        this.views = [{name: 'one'}, {name: 'two'}, {name: 'three'}, {name: 'four'}];
        this.activeViewObservable = new Observable<ViewModel>(observer => this.viewObserver = observer);
    }

    public setView(view:ViewModel):void {
        this.viewObserver.next(view); // load values here
      }
}
```

I use a component called `viewcomponent` here:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'viewcomponent',
    directives: [
        ROUTER_DIRECTIVES
    ],
    template: `
        <div class="tab-pane" [ngClass]="{ 'active': isActive() }">
            ...
        </div>
      `
})
export class ViewComponent {
    // these values are always the last view. why???
    @Input() viewName:string;
    @Input() activeViewObservable:Observable<TabViewModel>;

    private activeView:ViewModel;

    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.activeViewObservable.subscribe( //listen to values loaded with the viewObserver
            activeView => {this.activeView = activeView;},
            error => console.error(error));
    }

    public isActive():boolean {
        let bool:boolean = false;
        if (this.activeView) {
            console.log(this.viewName); // <---- this value is always the last view, 'four'
            bool = this.activeView.name == this.viewName;
        }
        console.log(bool);
        return bool;
    }
}
```

The data model im using is here:

```
export interface ViewModel {
    name: string;
}
```

I'm trying to load an observer with values in the `AppComponent` and then subscribe to them in the child. However, the value emitted by the observable is always the last element.

I want to call the `setView` method in the parent and then apply a class to that specific child view.

Answer (score 1):

**Possible solution:** use `Subject` if you want to call `.next()` on an `Observer` outside of the instantiation of the `Observable`. `Subject` behaves as both. You can subscribe to them separately from where you pass events to it. **[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/SRTTCg8BNfJDIglPKarg?p=preview)**

**Why your code does not work?**

Your code that uses rxjs could write like this:

```
let viewObserver;
const myObservable = new Observable(observer => {
  viewObserver = observer;
});

myObservable.subscribe(
  activeView => {
    console.log(1, activeView);
  },
  error => console.error(error));

myObservable.subscribe(
  activeView => {
    console.log(2, activeView);
  },
  error => console.error(error));

viewObserver.next({ name: 'one' });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/t5z9jyf0/

What is expected output?

```
2, { name: 'one' }
```

**Why?**

Let's open rxjs documentation

- http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#subscribing-to-observables

Key point there is:

> When calling observable.subscribe with an Observer, the function
>   subscribe in Observable.create(function subscribe(observer) {...}) is
>   run for that given Observer. Each call to observable.subscribe
>   triggers its own independent setup for that given Observer.

```
let viewObserver;
var myObservable = new Observable<ViewModel>(function subscribe(observer) {
  console.log(observer, observer.destination._next);
  viewObserver = observer;
});

myObservable.subscribe( // this triggers subscribe function above
  activeView => {
    console.log(1, activeView);
  },
  error => console.error(error));


myObservable.subscribe( // this also triggers subscribe function above
  activeView => {
    console.log(2, activeView);
  },
  error => console.error(error));


viewObserver.next({ name: 'one' }); // notify subscriptions
```

https://jsfiddle.net/t5z9jyf0/1/

So that code does not work because after

```
myObservable.subscribe(
  activeView => {
    console.log(2, activeView);
  },
  error => console.error(error));
```

method is executed, `viewObserver` will be overwritten and it will be `Subscriber` object from `activeView => { console.log(2, activeView); }`, so `viewObserver.next` will give us

```
console.log(2, { name: 'one' });
```

That's why only last subscription is executed